# Installing VS.NET on a 64-bit Computer

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

I am trying to install Visual Studio .NET on a Windows 7 64-bit computer. When I run the setup, I get this error message:

"Unable to install Visual Studio .NET on a 64-bit operating system."

Searching Google tells me other people have run into this, but I don't see any solutions. Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: what version of VS are you using ?

Comment: Visual Studio .NET like VS 2002?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio .NET (2002), not VS.NET 2003.

Comment: Late comment I know. But I'm trying to install VS 2002 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine also. According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907750, it's not supported. So what I'm going to do is create a 32-bit virtual machine and install it on there.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't install VS.NET on a 64-bit computer. You can install it on Windows 7 x86.

I was certain I saw claims that it worked on Windows 7 x64, but I've since become convinced that won't work.

If you really need it on a 64-bit computer, create a 32-bit virtual machine and install it there.